# Is it possible to use the DPDK KNI as a TUN Device

Tags: dpdk

I've been hitting the performance limits of the kernel TUN driver and I'm looking to the DPDK KNI driver as an alternative since it cites itself as a replacement for Linux TUN/TAP and provides a more efficient interface to get packets to the network stack.

I've been experimenting with it as a replacement, but it operates at L2 and I'm unsure how to configure the interface or what scaffolding I need to build to make it behave as an L3 point-to-point TUN driver. I can see packets (with Ethernet headers) being presented to the interface, including a DHCP packet from the OS, but I'm not sure how to respond to these messages and a short while adding an IP to the interface the kernel drops it.

Is it possible to use the KNI driver as a replacement for TUN and, if so, is there any existing tooling / open-source projects to use the KNI interface as a L3 TUN device?

Comment: DPDK has TUN PMD, which is IP layer. This can be activated by `--vdev=net_tun0, iface=test`. Can you help me understand if you are trying `net_tap` or `net_tun` in DPDK ? DPDK KNI is similar to DPDK TAP where L2 header is expected.

Comment: Sorry I probably explained this badly. I would like to replace the use of a tun driver in an existing application with something that avoids syscalls. I've found the difference in performance with spectre mits enabled is upwards of 40% for our application and io_uring doesn't help. I'm looking for a proprietary kernel module and kni seems like it could do it but I'm unsure how to get started (past my initial exploration).

Comment: I think it is possible (not tried it out) because when you inject TUN packet (IP + payload) to KNI it converts to sk_buff and put in routing stack. On reverse direction packets from routing stack with destination IP of KNI will be forwarded theoretically copied as rte_mbuf.

Comment: Thanks, I finally got it working in the end. By adding IFF_TUN to the driver initialization and recompiling I can make it attach as an L3 device (just IP packets) rather than L2 (with the Ethernet frames and ARP). The issues I had with the IP being removed were the default behaviour for dhcpd, not the OS, disabling the network manager hardcoding static routes solved that issue.

Comment: nice to hear that you were able to solve the issue by adding KNi as TUN interface. I always had the feeling in KNI driver code one needs to do extra like modify `kni_net_header_ops` function `kni_net_header` to prevent from inject the Etherenet header with src-mac, dst-mac and type. But looks like you did not do those. Strange but intersting.